# parbox vertical alignment after brace in equation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, boxes

In the code below, I am trying to center the parboxes vertically, relative to the braces. I have been playing around with the position argument, to no avail. Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
%%%%%PREAMBLE
\documentclass[letter,12pt,twoside]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

%%%%%PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} % Margins
\usepackage{setspace} % Interline spacing

%%%%%BODY

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \Delta_{st} WMA_{m,i}   & \left. \begin{aligned}
                                    = \phantom{-} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\left(\frac{Pop_{j,t}}{\tau_{i,j,t}^4}\right)-\left(\frac{Pop_{j,s}}{\tau_{i,j,s}^4}\right)\right]Wet_{j,s}Wet_{j,t}}
                                \end{aligned} \right\} \parbox{3cm}{\singlespacing \centering AAAAAAAAAA \\ BB} \\
                                & \left. \begin{aligned}
                                    \phantom{=} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\frac{Pop_{j,t}}{\tau_{i,j,t}^4}\right]\left(1-Wet_{j,s}\right)Wet_{j,t}}  \\
                                    \phantom{=} - \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\frac{Pop_{j,s}}{\tau_{i,j,s}^4}\right]Wet_{j,s}\left(1-Wet_{j,t}\right)}
                                \end{aligned} \right\} \parbox{3cm}{\singlespacing \centering CC \\ DD \\ EEEEEEEEEEE \\ FF}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to issue `\singlespacing`, which is causing your vertical mis-alignment. Regardless, you can also use a `tabular` to stack content vertically within math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,setspace}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % Margins

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \Delta_{st} WMA_{m,i}   & \left. \begin{aligned}
                                    = \phantom{-} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\left(\frac{Pop_{j,t}}{\tau_{i,j,t}^4}\right)-\left(\frac{Pop_{j,s}}{\tau_{i,j,s}^4}\right)\right]Wet_{j,s}Wet_{j,t}}
                                \end{aligned} \right\} \parbox{3cm}{\centering AAAAAAAAAA \\ BB} \\
                                & \left. \begin{aligned}
                                    \phantom{=} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\frac{Pop_{j,t}}{\tau_{i,j,t}^4}\right]\left(1-Wet_{j,s}\right)Wet_{j,t}}  \\
                                    \phantom{=} - \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\frac{Pop_{j,s}}{\tau_{i,j,s}^4}\right]Wet_{j,s}\left(1-Wet_{j,t}\right)}
                                \end{aligned} \right\} \parbox{3cm}{\centering CC \\ DD \\ EEEEEEEEEEE \\ FF}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \Delta_{st} WMA_{m,i}   & \left. \begin{aligned}
                                    = \phantom{-} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\left(\frac{Pop_{j,t}}{\tau_{i,j,t}^4}\right)-\left(\frac{Pop_{j,s}}{\tau_{i,j,s}^4}\right)\right]Wet_{j,s}Wet_{j,t}}
                                \end{aligned} \right\}
                                \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{3cm}}
                                  AAAAAAAAAA \\ BB
                                \end{tabular} \\
                                & \left. \begin{aligned}
                                    \phantom{=} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\frac{Pop_{j,t}}{\tau_{i,j,t}^4}\right]\left(1-Wet_{j,s}\right)Wet_{j,t}}  \\
                                    \phantom{=} - \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j \in J}{\left[\frac{Pop_{j,s}}{\tau_{i,j,s}^4}\right]Wet_{j,s}\left(1-Wet_{j,t}\right)}
                                \end{aligned} \right\}
                                \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{3cm}}
                                  CC \\ DD \\ EEEEEEEEEEE \\ FF
                                \end{tabular}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```